# Refresh Location or move a JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

So I am building a board game and I cant find a way to move the label with the pawn image whenever I press the Roll Dice button.

It seems that I don't access the class that builds the window/frame but the only thing that managed to half work is the create again and again the window with new Constraints.

Also the action listeners are on a different class and I would like to keep them there. Also I know my code is a mess, and I will clean it up as soon as I find something that works and actually moves the pawns.  These are the graphics.

```
public class Dashboard extends JPanel{

    JButton   buttonroll1=new JButton("Roll Dice");
    JButton  buttonroll2=new JButton("Roll Dice");
    JButton  mydeal1=new JButton("My Deal Cards");
    JButton  mydeal2=new JButton("My Deal Cards");
    JButton  getloan1=new JButton("Get Loan");
    JButton  getloan2=new JButton("Get Loan");
    JButton  endturn1=new JButton("End Turn");
    JButton  endturn2=new JButton("End Turn");
    static public   GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    public  JFrame frame = new JFrame("PayDay");
    public  GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    public  JLabel label11=new JLabel();
    Icon mailIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/mailCard.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(150,80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));;
    JButton buttonmail = new JButton(mailIcon);
    Icon dealIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/dealCard.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(150,80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));;
    JButton buttondeal = new JButton(dealIcon);

    public Dashboard(Player player1,Player player2,Positions pos,int turn){
        Game listener=new Game(buttonroll1,buttonroll2,mydeal1,mydeal2,getloan1,getloan2,endturn1,endturn2, buttondeal, buttonmail);
        String path = "C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/";
        frame.setLayout(layout);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        String[] days={"Start","Monday","Tuesday","Wednseday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednseday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednseday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednseday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday","Monay","Tuesday","Wednesday"};
        int m=0;
        //Labels for the Days+Icons
        for(int y=1;y<8;y=y+2){
            for(int x=0;x<7;x++){
        JLabel label0=new JLabel();
        JLabel label1=new JLabel(days[m]+" "+m);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        Color color = new Color(255,255,0);
        panel.setBackground(color);
        c.gridx=x;
        c.gridy=y;
        panel.setBackground(color);
        panel.add(label1);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel,c);
        label0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(path+pos.position_message[m]).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        m++;
        c.gridx=x;
        c.gridy=y+1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(label0,c);
            }
        }
        //Last Labels for Days+Icons    
        for(int y=9;y<10;y++){
            for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
        JLabel label1=new JLabel(days[m]+" "+m);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        Color color = new Color(255,255,0);
        c.gridx=x;
        c.gridy=y;
        panel.setBackground(color);
        panel.add(label1);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel,c);
        JLabel label0=new JLabel();
        label0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(path+pos.position_message[m]).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        m++;
        c.gridx=x;
        c.gridy=y+1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(label0,c);
            }
        }
        //Jackpot icon label
        JLabel label0=new JLabel();
        label0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/jackpot.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(200, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx=5;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        c.gridy=10;     
        frame.getContentPane().add(label0,c);
        //Payday header logo label
        JLabel labelheader=new JLabel();
        labelheader.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/logo.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(700, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        c.gridwidth=8;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelheader, c);


        //Player 1 box layout with player1 info and buttons 
        JLabel jplayer=new JLabel(" Player"+1);
        JLabel jspace1=new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel jspace2=new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel jspace3=new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel jspace4=new JLabel(" ");    
        JLabel jplayermoney=new JLabel(" Money: "+player1.totalmoney);
        JLabel jplayerloan=new JLabel(" Loan: "+player1.timesloan);
        JLabel jbills=new JLabel(" Bills: "+player1.bills);
        Box box1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        jplayer.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jplayer);
        jspace1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jspace1);
        jplayermoney.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jplayermoney);
        jspace2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jspace2);
        jplayerloan.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jplayerloan);
        jspace3.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jspace3);
        jbills.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jbills);    
        jspace4.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(jspace4);
        box1.setOpaque(true);
        Color color= new Color(240,240,240);
        box1.setBackground(color);
        buttonroll1.addActionListener(listener);
        buttonroll1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(buttonroll1);
        box1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        mydeal1.addActionListener(listener);
        mydeal1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(mydeal1);
        box1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        getloan1.addActionListener(listener);
        getloan1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1.add(getloan1);
        box1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        c.insets=new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=4;
        c.gridx=8;
        c.gridy=0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(box1,c);
        //Player2 boxlayout info+buttons
        JLabel jplayern=new JLabel(" Player"+2);
        JLabel jspace1n=new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel jspace2n=new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel jspace3n=new JLabel(" ");
        JLabel jspace4n=new JLabel(" ");    
        JLabel jplayermoneyn=new JLabel(" Money: "+player2.totalmoney);
        JLabel jplayerloann=new JLabel(" Loan: "+player2.timesloan);
        JLabel jbillsn=new JLabel(" Bills: "+player2.bills);
        Box box1n = Box.createVerticalBox();
        jplayern.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jplayern);
        jspace1n.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jspace1n);
        jplayermoney.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jplayermoneyn);
        jspace2n.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jspace2n);
        jplayerloann.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jplayerloann);
        jspace3n.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jspace3n);
        jbills.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jbillsn);    
        jspace4n.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(jspace4n);
        box1n.setOpaque(true);
        Color colorn= new Color(240,240,240);
        box1n.setBackground(colorn);
        buttonroll2.addActionListener(listener);
        buttonroll2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(buttonroll2);
        box1n.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        mydeal2.addActionListener(listener);
        mydeal2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(mydeal2);
        box1n.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        getloan2.addActionListener(listener);
        getloan2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box1n.add(getloan2);
        box1n.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        c.insets=new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=4;
        c.gridx=8;
        c.gridy=7;
        frame.getContentPane().add(box1n,c);

        //Second boxlayout inside gribgalayout cell for player1 Dice icon/end turn button
        Box box2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JLabel labeldice=new JLabel();
        labeldice.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/dice-1.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        box2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,90)));
        box2.add(labeldice);
        endturn1.addActionListener(listener);
        box2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        endturn1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box2.add(endturn1);
        box2.setOpaque(true);
        Color colork= new Color(240,240,240);
        box2.setBackground(colork);
        c.insets=new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=4;
        c.gridx=9;
        c.gridy=0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(box2,c);
         //Second boxlayout inside gribgalayout cell for player2 Dice icon/end turn button             
        Box box2v = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JLabel labeldicev=new JLabel();
        labeldicev.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/dice-1.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        box2v.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,90)));
        box2v.add(labeldicev);
        endturn2.addActionListener(listener);
        box2v.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        endturn2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        box2v.add(endturn2);
        box2v.setOpaque(true);
        Color colorkv= new Color(240,240,240);
        box2v.setBackground(colorkv);
        c.insets=new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=4;
        c.gridx=9;
        c.gridy=7;
        frame.getContentPane().add(box2v,c);

        //dealbutton
        buttondeal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 80));
        buttondeal.addActionListener(listener);
        c.insets=new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridx=8;
        c.gridy=4;
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttondeal, c);

        //Mail button
        buttonmail.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 80));
        buttonmail.addActionListener(listener);
        c.insets=new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        c.gridx=9;
        c.gridy=4;
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonmail, c);
        //Infobox box layout for players info during their respective turns  
        Box box3 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Info Box");
        box3.add(label2);
        if(turn==1){
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(player1.months+" Months left");
        box3.add(label3);}
        else if(turn==2){
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(player2.months+" Months left");
        box3.add(label3);}
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Turn: Player"+turn);
        box3.add(label4);
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Info Box");
        box3.add(label5);
        box3.setOpaque(true);
        Color colorl= new Color(240,240,240);
        box3.setBackground(colorl);
        c.insets=new Insets(70,10,0,0);
        c.gridwidth=2;
        c.gridx=8;
        c.gridy=2;
        frame.getContentPane().add(box3, c);
        //Blue pawn label and positioning based on player1 position
        label11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/pawn_blue.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(50,50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));       
        c.insets=new Insets(0,0,100,0);
        int o=player1.position;
        int r=1;
        if(player1.position<=6){
        c.gridx=player1.position;
        c.gridy=1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(label11, c,0);
        }
        else {
            while(o>6){
            o=o-7;
            r=r+3;
            }
            c.gridx=o;
            c.gridy=r;
            frame.getContentPane().add(label11, c,0);
        }
        //Yellow pawn Label and positioning based on the player 2 position
        JLabel label12=new JLabel();
        label12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/pawn_yellow.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(50,50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));     
        c.insets=new Insets(0,50,100,0);
        int b=player2.position;
        int n=1;
        if(player2.position<=6){
        c.gridx=player2.position;
        c.gridy=1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(label12, c,0);
        }
        else {
            while(b>6){
            b=b-7;
            n=n+3;
            }
            c.gridx=b;
            c.gridy=n;
            frame.getContentPane().add(label12, c,0);
        }

        //Green background label
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Stratos/Desktop/252/Project/src/Input/Icons/bg_green.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(1020, 730, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
        c.gridwidth=11;
        c.gridheight=12;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.insets=new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        frame.getContentPane().add(background,c);
         System.out.println("Mphka");
  }
```

These are the action listeners for the pawns. `buttonroll1` is blue pawn and `buttonroll2` is yellow pawn.

```
    public void play_game(){
        db = new Dashboard(player1, player2, pos, a);
        db.frame.pack();
        db.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             Object src=e.getSource();
                if (src==buttonroll1 && turn==1) {
                  bpos.setPosition(player1, dice, pos);
                  db.frame.getContentPane().add(db.label11, db.c);
                  db.validate();
                  db.repaint();
                }
                else if(src==buttonroll2 && turn==2){
                  bpos.setPosition(player2, dice, pos);
                }
}
```

Also, the following is experimental code trying to solve my problem; can be changed/removed.

`db.frame.getContentPane().add(db.label11, db.c);
 db.validate();
 db.repaint();`

Comment: You should reformat your question. It is pretty impossible to read and may get down voted fast.

Comment: *"Also i know my code is a mess and i will clean it up as soon as i find something that works.."* We'll help you find something that works as soon as you take enough effort to clean it up.  Do you see the dilemma? More generally: for better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).